# How to convert Optional<Dictionary<String, Any>> to Dictionary<String, Any> to send Alamofire (5.4.4) post request with json paramters?

Tags: swift, django, alamofire

```
class func postLoginRequest(url: String, parameters: Parameters?, success: @escaping (Any) -> Void, failure: @escaping (NetworkError) -> Void) {
             
             
             if Network.isAvailable {
                 
                 let param : [String : Any] = [
                     "username" : "x",
                     "password" : "x"
                 ]
                 print (type(of: param))
                 print(param)

                 print(type(of: parameters))
                 print(parameters)
                
                 let manager = Alamofire.Session.default
                 manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = Constants.NetworkError.timeOutInterval
                 manager.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default ).validate(statusCode: 200..<600).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in ...
```

My data output like given in bellow;

```
Dictionary<String, Any>

["username": "x", "password": "x"]

Optional<Dictionary<String, Any>>

Optional(["username": Optional(<TextFieldEffects.HoshiTextField: 0x11c054600; baseClass = UITextField; frame = (41 10; 286 40); text = 'x'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2821b45d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x282f855c0>>), "password": Optional(<TextFieldEffects.HoshiTextField: 0x11c043600; baseClass = UITextField; frame = (41 10; 286 40); text = 'x'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2821afe40>; layer = <CALayer: 0x282f849c0>>)])
```

When ı use param as a parameters no problem. I can get username and password in backend (DJango) for jwt auth. But ı cant when ı use parameters as parameters value. How can do this convertion to send json body data.

Comment: Don't send the `UITextField` as value, send the `textField.text` property! And unwrap if if needed.

Comment: @Larme Thanks a lot. It's my fault I missed it.

Comment: Aside from what your asking, this code doesn't do what you think it does. First, don't check network availability first. Apple says don't do it, it won't work like you think. Second, you modifications to `URLSessionConfiguration` after the configuration has been added to a `URLSession` have no affect, so your setting of `timeoutIntervalForRequest` doesn't do anything. Third, `timeoutIntervalForRequest` is not the same thing as the `URLRequest`'s timeout, so it's probably not what you want in the first place.

Comment: @JonShier thanks your opinions.  I'll take note and check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [safely unwrap](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) to convert anything from Optional to Type

```
let myDict: [String : Any]? = ["john" : "Appleseed"]
// 1. Using guard statements
guard let unwraped: [String : Any] = myDict else { 
    // The value is nil
    return 
}
// 2. Using if statements
if let unwraped: [String : Any] = myDict { 
    // unwraped value
}
else { 
    // The value is nil
}
// 3. Using force unwrap (be careful, this will crash your app if myDict is nil)
let unwraped = myDict!
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake is sending the UITextField as value. I missed it. First I fixed this. After that ı use URLEncoding.httpBody for encoding data.

```
if Network.isAvailable {
                 
                 let manager = Alamofire.Session.default
                 manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = Constants.NetworkError.timeOutInterval
                 manager.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody ).validate(statusCode: 200..<600).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
```

Thanks.